# How to set fontSize and fontWeight with :table-header-style in Quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I tried to set the font size in the header of a q-table component in Quasar, but it's not doing anything... Same with the font weight. Strangely enough, the font, color, and background color are all working.

Comment: can you paste snippet of  your css

Comment: I ran into this as well, and don't see a way without custom CSS. The docs say "which is a TR" but the font-weight and font-size are overwritten at `.q-table th` (which is below the TR holding the `table-header-style` value).

Answer (score 3):

This Question seems a bit old and you probably found your way.
Anyway, I had the same problem in adding classes and style to the table header.
The only thing that worked for me was using headerStyle on the column definition. I couldn´t get headerClasses with 'text-bold' for example to work either.

Example:

```
const columns = [{
    label: "Username", 
    field: "user_name", 
    align: 'left', 
    headerStyle: "font-weight: bold"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use Header Cell Slots:

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#header-slots

```html
<q-table>
  <template v-slot:header-cell="props">
    <q-th :props="props" style="font-size: large">
      {{ props.col.label }}
    </q-th>
  </template>
</q-table>
```

This avoids having to add the style manually to every column definition.